# Tensorflow image recognition folder Access is denied

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow

Working on the tensorflow page for image recognition:

https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/image_recognition

Here is the file:

https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/tutorials/image/imagenet/classify_image.py

I added a folder location:

```
 parser.add_argument(
     '--image_file',
     type=str,
     default='C:/',
     help='Absolute path to image file.'

 )
```

I get this error:

```
 tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.UnknownError: NewRandomAccessFile failed to Create/Open: C:/ : Access is denied. ; Input/output error
```

How do I resolve this error?